# How do I list a single contracting job for multiple companies on my resume?

Tags: resume, contracts

I'm currently working for multiple companies.

My work site is at one company(let's call it Company A). I will be working at A for the duration of my employment. This company is contracting another company, B, and I was interviewed by B as a part of a staffing firm C.

Company A is far better known than both B and C.

I'd like to list a contracting job on my resume under all of these companies. How do I do that?

added details: Company A won a bid for a city project(company D I guess). They hired company B to do a portion of the work. Company B requires more employees so they contracted a staffing firm, Company C. Company C contacted me for an interview with company B at company A's location. Actual work done is at parts of the city(company D) and meetings at company A. Company B is headquartered in a different state but has an office at company A.

Sorry for the headache.

Comment: I'd suggest you add more details in your question.

Comment: I hope i was more clear in the added details.

Answer (score 3):

Company A it is. This is what you should represent. All middle tiers are inconsequential

Comment: I agree there is no need to list staffing agency C, but listing (sub)contractors can add value to a resumé. I used to work for a consultancy whose clients were far higher-profile than the consultancy itself, and I list each of those clients' engagements separately in my LinkedIn profile.

Comment: Or "contacting: company A..." If you want to be 110% accurate.